# Why firebase_firestore security rules not worked for document read

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am currently working on a a app and in that user needs to make a new account. Your Enters first name and last name then the app automatically suggest a username which is unique and it will be the document name of that user. I had set the firestore secutity rules as follows,

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
```

after user enters the username it checks that the username used or not before move to the next screen.

```
  Future<bool> checkUsernameExist(String name)async{
    bool usernameExistSate;
    await firestore.collection('users').doc(name).get().then((docSnapShot){
      if(docSnapShot.exists){
        usernameExistSate = true;
      }else{
        usernameExistSate = false;
      }
    });
    return usernameExistSate;
  }
```

Currently above system works fine without any problem. But I have a problem, With the firebase security rules sets to below condition how users able to read the documents to check the similar document names are present?

> allow read, write: if request.auth != null;

Comment: The user needs to be signed in before they can read that collection. If that is a problem fr your use-case, consider not requiring them to be signed in.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would not use the usernames to store your data in firestore but the uid provided when you are authenicated with google auth. This will allow you much safer access to the database with security rules like this:
rules_version = '2';

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId}/{document=**} {
      allow read, write, update, delete: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      allow create: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

For your second problem I would just create a second collection in the root of the firebase project named for example `usernames` with all usernames stored in a big list so you can query them safely via the firebase API. For that to be possible you have to give the authenticated device access to this collection too via for example adding this under

> match /users/...

```
match /usernames/{document=**} {
      allow read, write, update, delete, create: if request.auth != null;
}
```

Of course then, you have to keep track of both lists when making changes. But this way an authenticated user has only access to his data and all usernames in the worst case.